# Django: new post notification

Tags: django, templates, time, notifications, render

I'm trying to do a simple notification when some has posted a new forum post. This used to work in the past but now it doesn't for some reason. I don't know what I've done to break it. In my index.html template I do a time comparison:

```
<li class="{% if topic.topic_last_post.post_time > request.user.last_login %}bold notification{% endif %}">...</li>
```

The comparison works. However it seems that request.user.last_login is updated before the template is rendered. This is my view code. Is it correct?

```
class FrontpageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "frontpage/index.html"

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        t = TemplateView.render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            self.request.user.last_login = now
            self.request.user.save()
        return t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's more or less the point of the new `TemplateResponse` class, which is used by `TemplateView`  - it allows you to modify items after calling `render_to_response` and have those modifications show up in the output.

To explicitly disable that, you can just call `render()` on the result of the `render_to_response`.

```
response = super(FrontpageView, self).render_to_response(content, **response_kwargs)
reponse.render()
if ...

return response
```

(Also note, you should use `super` rather than specifying the class name directly.)